# Detecting missing single parentheses in the presence of potentially missing double parentheses

Tags: r, regex

I have partly faulty transcriptions, which I want to clean-up:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:14,
  Utterance = c("((v: laughs))",                                                # Double parentheses -- transcriber comment
                "(1.620)",                                                      # OK -- pause
                "doesn't like it [((silent m & t: leaning forward r hand))]",   # Double parentheses -- silent gesture
                "<the glasses?> (.) °or what°",                                 # OK -- micro-pause
                "°°phew°° ok(h)ay",                                             # OK -- within-word laughter
                "just get over it ((name ID08.B))=",                            # Double parentheses -- anonymization
                "°are our phones¿ (ins-) no°",                                  # OK -- candidate hearing
                "without parentheses",                                          # no parentheses used!
                "like ((silent m: fist pump)",                                  # Double parentheses -- silent gesture --> closing bracket missing
                "(1.620",                                                       # --> closing bracket is missing
                "(°SC one?° (1.231) right?",                                    # --> closing bracket is missing
                "[((v: laughs))] (v: gasps))",                                  # Double parentheses -- transcriber comment --> opening bracket is missing
                "°°phew°° okh)ay",                                              # --> opening bracket is missing
                "yep v: yawns)) u:m")                                           # Double parentheses -- transcriber comment --> opening brackets is missing
)
```

The focus here is *detecting* `Utterance`s where **single round brackets are missing**. The problem I'm struggling with is the fact that in `Utterance` there may also be items wrapped in **double round brackets** - which may be missing as well. I try to *exclude* double round brackets from the detection algorithm by using negative lookarounds (items wrapped in double parentheses have `name` or `silent` or `v:` right after the opening bracket), but the success is limited:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    # extract `(` and `)`, then paste them together in a string in a new column `delims`:
    delims = lapply(str_extract_all(Utterance, "(?<!\\()\\((?!(name|silent|v:))|(?<!(name|silent|v:)[^)]{1,50}\\))\\)"), paste0, collapse = ""),
    # test whether the number of `()` combinations equals half the number of characters in `delims`:
    valid = str_count(delims, "\\(\\)") == nchar(delims)/2) %>%
  # filter on those rows where the test returns FALSE:
  filter(valid == FALSE)
  id                   Utterance delims valid
1 10                      (1.620      ( FALSE
2 11   (°SC one?° (1.231) right?    (() FALSE
3 12 [((v: laughs))] (v: gasps))    ()) FALSE
4 13             °°phew°° okh)ay      ) FALSE
5 14          yep v: yawns)) u:m      ) FALSE
```

The expected result is this:

```
  id                   Utterance delims valid
1 10                      (1.620      ( FALSE
2 11   (°SC one?° (1.231) right?    (() FALSE
3 13             °°phew°° okh)ay      ) FALSE
```

How can the detection be improved?

**EDIT**:

With the help by @Onyambu's solution, I've cobbled together this solution adapted to my prior attempts:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    # remove double parentheses with all conent where present or expected:
    Utterance_temp = gsub('[(]{,2}(name|silent|v:)[^()]+[)]+', '', Utterance),
    # extract remaining `(` and `)`, then paste them together in a string in a new column `delims`:
    delims = lapply(str_extract_all(Utterance_temp, "\\(|\\)"), paste0, collapse = ""),
    # test whether the number of `()` combinations equals half the number of characters in `delims`:
    valid = str_count(delims, "\\(\\)") == nchar(delims)/2) %>%
  # remove `Utterance_temp`:
  select(-Utterance_temp) %>%
  # filter on those rows where the test returns FALSE:
  filter(valid == FALSE)
```

Comment: Does missing round brackets mean unequal opening and closing paranthesis? If not, could you elaborate as to why id 9 and id 12 are left out of the final data?

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. id 9 `like ((silent m: fist pump)`should not be matched as this is a case of missing **double** round bracket (after `pump)`); same for id 12 `[((v: laughs))] (v: gasps))`- again a case of missing double parentheses, here in front of `(v: gasps))`. As noted in the Q, double round parentheses are identifiably via `(name|silent|v:)`

Comment: will you consider something like `(1.4567 ((yuni))3434)` as okay or as missing both opening and clossing?

Comment: This kind of overlap does not occur in my data; also please note all double parenthetical expressions have this structure: `((name etc.` or `((silent etc.` or `((v: etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R, you could try:

```
transform(df, v = grepl('^(?=.*[()])(?!([^()]*)[(](?1)[)](?1))', 
                      gsub('[(]{,2}(name|silent|v:)[^()]+[)]+', '', Utterance),
                      perl = TRUE))

  id                                                  Utterance     v
1   1                                              ((v: laughs)) FALSE
2   2                                                    (1.620) FALSE
3   3 doesn't like it [((silent m & t: leaning forward r hand))] FALSE
4   4                               <the glasses?> (.) °or what° FALSE
5   5                                           °°phew°° ok(h)ay FALSE
6   6                          just get over it ((name ID08.B))= FALSE
7   7                                °are our phones¿ (ins-) no° FALSE
8   8                                        without parentheses FALSE
9   9                                like ((silent m: fist pump) FALSE
10 10                                                     (1.620  TRUE
11 11                                  (°SC one?° (1.231) right?  TRUE
12 12                                [((v: laughs))] (v: gasps)) FALSE
13 13                                            °°phew°° okh)ay  TRUE
14 14                                         yep v: yawns)) u:m FALSE
15 15                <the glasses?> (. °or what° ((name ID07.A))  TRUE
```

EDIT:

```
df |>
   transform(v = grepl('^(?=.*[()])(?!([^()]*)[(](?1)[)](?1))', 
                    gsub('[(]{,2}(name|silent|v:)[^()]+[)]+', '', Utterance),
                   perl = TRUE)) |>
   subset(v)
   id                                   Utterance    v
10 10                                      (1.620 TRUE
11 11                   (°SC one?° (1.231) right? TRUE
13 13                             °°phew°° okh)ay TRUE
15 15 <the glasses?> (. °or what° ((name ID07.A)) TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was quite helpful. The idea of first removing all double-parentheses along with their content did the trick. I've adapted your solution to my previous solution in the edited Q.

Comment: Just one more question: I'm not familiar with this notation: `(?1)`- what does it mean/do?

Comment: @ChrisReuhlemann, `(?R)` is for recursion, `(?1)` is to recurse the first group  etc. While `\1` catures the CONTENTS of the first group, `(?1)` captures the PATTERN and not the Contents that gives you the first group.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, you do not need lapply, just `gsub("[^()]", "", Utterance_temp)` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to completely exclude Utterance strings with double brackets? If yes, I think this solves your problem

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:14,
  Utterance = c("((v: laughs))",                                                # Double parentheses -- transcriber comment
                "(1.620)",                                                      # OK -- pause
                "doesn't like it [((silent m & t: leaning forward r hand))]",   # Double parentheses -- silent gesture
                "<the glasses?> (.) °or what°",                                 # OK -- micro-pause
                "°°phew°° ok(h)ay",                                             # OK -- within-word laughter
                "just get over it ((name ID08.B))=",                            # Double parentheses -- anonymization
                "°are our phones¿ (ins-) no°",                                  # OK -- candidate hearing
                "without parentheses",                                          # no parentheses used!
                "like ((silent m: fist pump)",                                  # Double parentheses -- silent gesture --> closing bracket missing
                "(1.620",                                                       # --> closing bracket is missing
                "(°SC one?° (1.231) right?",                                    # --> closing bracket is missing
                "[((v: laughs))] (v: gasps))",                                  # Double parentheses -- transcriber comment --> opening bracket is missing
                "°°phew°° okh)ay",                                              # --> opening bracket is missing
                "yep v: yawns)) u:m")                                           # Double parentheses -- transcriber comment --> opening brackets is missing
)

df
#>    id                                                  Utterance
#> 1   1                                              ((v: laughs))
#> 2   2                                                    (1.620)
#> 3   3 doesn't like it [((silent m & t: leaning forward r hand))]
#> 4   4                               <the glasses?> (.) °or what°
#> 5   5                                           °°phew°° ok(h)ay
#> 6   6                          just get over it ((name ID08.B))=
#> 7   7                                °are our phones¿ (ins-) no°
#> 8   8                                        without parentheses
#> 9   9                                like ((silent m: fist pump)
#> 10 10                                                     (1.620
#> 11 11                                  (°SC one?° (1.231) right?
#> 12 12                                [((v: laughs))] (v: gasps))
#> 13 13                                            °°phew°° okh)ay
#> 14 14                                         yep v: yawns)) u:m

df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(
    opening = stringr::str_count(Utterance, "\\("),
    closing = stringr::str_count(Utterance, "\\)"),
    double_br = stringr::str_detect(Utterance, "\\({2}|\\){2}")
  ) |> 
  dplyr::filter(opening != closing, double_br == FALSE)
#>   id                 Utterance opening closing double_br
#> 1 10                    (1.620       1       0     FALSE
#> 2 11 (°SC one?° (1.231) right?       2       1     FALSE
#> 3 13           °°phew°° okh)ay       0       1     FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the try but I'm afraid it's not as simple. There may be strings where a single parenthesis is missing and there are double paretheses in the same string: `"<the glasses?> (. °or what° ((name ID07.A))"`. Your method misses out on these.